# Python Input validation

Tags: python, input, validation

I have a menu that will return 'e' unless the input is d or D.
I would like to do it without making another variable and doing it on one line

```
encrypt = 'd' if (raw_input("Encrypt or Decrypt a file(E/d):") == ('d' or 'D')) else 'e'
```

[Edit]
Ok here is a harder one

How can I do the same for this

```
file_text = 'a.txt' if (raw_input("File name(a.txt):")=='a.txt' else [What I typed in]
```

Comment: Why one line? It makes your code harder to understand for most people

Comment: @BryanOakley It looks too drawn out if it is `encrypt = raw_input("Encrypt or Decrypt a file(E/d):" if encrypt != 'd' or encrypt != 'D': encrypt != 'e'` I also like to look for unusual and different ways to do programing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
encrypt = 'd' if raw_input("Encrypt or decrypt a file (E/d):") in ('d', 'D') else 'e'
```

Alternatively, you can just convert the input to lowercase and compare it to 'd':

```
encrypt = 'd' if raw_input("Encrypt or decrypt a file (E/d):").lower() == 'd' else 'e'
```

Finally, if you want to ensure that they enter e or d, you can wrap it up in a while loop:

```
while True:
    encrypt = raw_input("Encrypt or decrypt a file (E/d):")

    # Convert to lowercase
    encrypt = encrypt.lower()

    # If it's e or d then break out of the loop
    if encrypt in ('e', 'd'):
        break

    # Otherwise, it'll loop back and ask them to input again
```

Edit: To answer your second question, you can use a lambda for it I guess?

```
file_text = (lambda default, inp: default if inp.lower() == default else inp)("a.txt", raw_input("File name(a.txt):"))
```

Although, this is clearly a bit obtuse and too "clever" by half.

Comment: You can also try `raw_input("...").lower() == 'd'`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I figured I'd try staying closer to the original snippet.

Comment: @AlexVidal I dont like loops for simple yes or no inputs. Instead I like to check the input `if non-default [do stuff] else its the default`

Answer (score 1):

Not really meant seriously but another 1-line solution (I don't think it's readable):

```
encrypt = {'d':'d','D':'d'}.get(raw_input("Encrypt or decrypt a file (E/d):"), 'e')
```

At least it's short. Sometimes a dictionary is actually useful for similar situations (if there are more choices).